# Convection-diffusion equation with an added $cu$ term

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have to numerically solve the equation
\begin{equation*}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} - D \Delta u + B \cdot \nabla u + c u = f
\end{equation*}
with non-homogeneous Neumann boundary conditions. Without the $c u$ term, this equation is the convection-diffusion equation. I have tried to figure out the physical significance of the extra $c u$ term, but I couldn't find anything. Do any of you know if this is a known equation that models some natural phenomenon?

Answer (score 1):

A term linear in $u$ is a birth/death term. The population grows or dies exponentially with
$$\partial_t \log u(t) ==-c $$

if all other terms are discarded, that means in spatial equilibrium.

The Div term is an effect of a moving system of coordinates

```
 $$ t-> t',  x->x' -v t',  \partial_t -> \partial_t' - v \partial_x $$
```

yielding (swap of a terms over the =,yields, sometimes, something new)

```
 $$ \vec x ->vec x - \vec B t   ,  \nabla .\ nabla -> \Delta - \Div \vec B  $$
```

This is called the Galilileo group of transformations to an uniform moving system of space-time coordinates.

Even if it is not a group in the canonical sense.

Evidently the central definitions of the norm of the time derivative is changed; in analytical mechanics its called "kinetic energy" which depends on the speed of the spatial coordinate system.